# Xcode disconnecting from simulator or device when going to homescreen

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to debug an handoff issue in Xcode, but the debugger disconnects every time I go to the device homescreen.  This happens on both the simulator and an actual device.

I have other apps where it works correctly; that is, it continues to debug when I go to the homescreen.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  I've rebooted Xcode and my Mac with no luck.

When running on the device, the log has a message that looks like:

```
Jun 28 16:36:31 Mikes-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [14593] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [3901/1307]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x16e246a38, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jun 28 16:36:31 Mikes-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [14593] <Warning>: Exiting.
Jun 28 16:36:31 Mikes-iPhone mediaserverd[14247] <Notice>: '' com.zzzzzz.appname(pid = 14594) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
```

I'd appreciate any ideas or suggestions....

Answer (score 0):

Well this was dumb.  At some point I had changed the "Application does not run in background" plist flag to YES.  Simply changing to NO fixed the problem.  Duh.